# Requests from AngularJS to Nodejs is getting refused because of CORS

Tags: http, nginx, node.js, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I have an AngularJS/NodeJs web app , and I'm using Nginx on the  DigitalOcean for the server , and I'm using CloudFlare as well.

The website was up and running with no problem , 1 week ago i , I visited the website to find that my index has been changed to ,

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Checked my Nginx config files to and i realized there's no problem at all with the configuration , **so I just deleted the index and I uploaded my old index back** and the website is up and running again but , ***i cant login anymore and i believe i cant make any api request.***

All i get when i try to login is this message from the console.

**Firefox**

> ```
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dev.website.com/api/auth/login.
> ```
>
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

**Chrome**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://dev.supplieson.com/api/auth/login' from origin
>   'http://dev.supplieson.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

This how my Nginx config looks like

```
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #server_name supplieson.com www.supplieson.com;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location ~ ^/images/(.*) {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/api/supplieson_backend/images/$1;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 1m;
        }
}
```

**Express app**

```
import cors from 'cors';

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: If you really have all those `>` in your config it's simply invalid. If your index suddenly changed shouldn't you be kind of surprised as to why it changed? What actually caused that? Did you try to set the proper headers? What site did you actually try to access? The `www` one the one without it or the `dev` site? So was it actually a cross request? What browser did you use?`

Comment: questions is updated i corrected some mistakes in the styling and also added the error i get from chrome and firefox

Comment: All of them has got the same error dev. and the main domain are uploaded on the same server and got the same problem but currently i'm trying to fix dev. first .

Comment: Why are you using an IP to access the site that isn't even associated with the tld? Why are you setting headers within your app rather than including them in your config? Did you verify whenever you can see those headers?

Comment: I get the same error from dev. or from the main domain , anyways i edited my question with the error from dev. .

one of the solutions i found is to put the settings in the app which obviously doesn't work . 

what's the best way to do so ? i tried postman but i got nothing.

Comment: @Flash giving that you _did_ manage to fix your configuration (your site is currently up and well!), would you be so kind as to post your fixes, for future reference? Thanks!